# Opening a new pane in a window resets window name

Tags: tmux

Whenever I open a new pane inside a named window, it resets the name of that window. This makes the naming unusable. How do I solve this/what am I doing wrong?

Say I renamed a window like so:

[image]

I then have:

[image]

But as soon as I open an additional pane it resets the window name:

[image]

Comment: How do you open a pane?

Comment: Using the command: `ctrl+b -> "`

Comment: Does window name change when you select the previous pane?

Comment: No, it does not change back. I have observed that the name does _not_ change on my laptop. So this behavior is specific to the environment on our compute cluster. But I do not know, what is causing it. Here are the contents of `.tmux.conf` on the cluster perhaps that helps(?): $ cat ~/.tmux.conf 
bind-key -n C-S-Left swap-window -t -1
bind-key -n C-S-Right swap-window -t +1

bind-key r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message "~/.tmux.conf reloaded"
bind-key M split-window -h "vim ~/.tmux.conf"

Comment: I tried removing `.tmux.conf` on the cluster so to have the vanilla tmux settings, but that does not resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something in your shell or terminal is automatically issuing a window rename command to tmux, either via `tmux rename-window '...'` or an escape sequence `printf '\ek...\e\\'`.

While it is easy to grep your config files for `rename-window` patterns, the same cannot be done easily for escape sequences, because those can be represented in many ways.

At least you can forbid window rename via escape sequence by disabling `allow-rename` option:

```
tmux set-option -wg allow-rename off
```

If that worked, now have a clue: check you shell config or terminal preferences.

Comment: `tmux set-option -wg allow-rename off` does the trick. The window is not renamed anymore, after running the command. Thanks. But I still don't know what is causing it.
You write: "check you shell config or terminal preferences."
Any suggestions on where to look (beyond the obvious ~/.bashrc and ~/.tmux.conf), which do not look suspicious?

Comment: Try grepping case-insensitive your `.bashrc` for `ek` or `033k` or `x1bk`. In case your `.bashrc` sources other scripts, you need to check those too.

Comment: I have not yet found the solution to the actual cause of the issue. But this provides an acceptable work-around until I (hopefully) find a solution for it. So I am accepting this. Thanks for your support!

Comment: `allow-rename off` *is* the solution. u cannot stop other programs from sending the rename sequences. all u can do is ignore them.

Comment: You can also add `set -x` to the beginning of `.bashrc` to see what exactly shell is executing. Create a new pane and check the output for `ek` / `033k` / `x1bk` sequences.